# Creating a gulpfile.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

I have an issue with gulp : since I updated it, I have a few errors when launching gulp watch. I think my gulpfile.js is not correct anymore, but I can't find the issue.

Could anybody help me create a functionning gulpfile?

Here are my current files

The gulpfile.js :

```
 /*----------  Sources  ----------*/

// css
var css_src = ['css/style.scss'];
var jshint_src = ['scripts/app.js'];
var js_global_src = [
'scripts/vendor/jquery-3.1.1.min.js',
'scripts/vendor/svg4everybody.min.js',
'scripts/vendor/modernizr-custom.js'].concat(jshint_src);


/*----------  Destinations  ----------*/

var css_dir_final = '';
var js_file_final = 'scripts.min.js';
var js_dir_final = 'scripts/';


/*----------  Monitoring  ----------*/

var watch_css = 'css/**/*.scss';
var watch_js = ['scripts/**/*.js', '!scripts/scripts.min.js'];


var gulp        = require( 'gulp' ),
plumber         = require( 'gulp-plumber' ),
sass            = require( 'gulp-sass' ),
postcss         = require( 'gulp-postcss' ),
cssnano         = require( 'cssnano' ),
autoprefixer    = require( 'autoprefixer' ),
banner          = require( 'gulp-banner' ),
combineMq       = require( 'gulp-combine-mq' ),
jshint          = require( 'gulp-jshint' ),
concat          = require( 'gulp-concat' ),
uglify          = require( 'gulp-uglify' ),
watch           = require( 'gulp-watch' ),
purify          = require( 'gulp-purifycss');


/*----------  Post CSS plugins  ----------*/

var plugins = [ autoprefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'iOS 7'] }), cssnano() ];



/*------ simplification du message d'erreur------*/

var display_error = function ( error ) {

    console.log( error.message );
    this.emit( 'end' );

};


gulp.task('css', function() {

gulp.src( css_src )
.pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: display_error }))
.pipe(sass({ precision: 3 }))
.pipe(combineMq())
.pipe(purify(['./public/app/**/*.js', './public/**/*.html']))
.pipe(postcss( plugins ))
.pipe(gulp.dest( css_dir_final ));
});


gulp.task('js', function() {

gulp.src( jshint_src )
.pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: display_error }))
.pipe(jshint())
.pipe(jshint.reporter( 'default' ));

gulp.src( js_global_src )
.pipe(plumber({ errorHandler: display_error }))
.pipe(concat( js_file_final ))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest( js_dir_final ));
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){

    gulp.watch( watch_css, gulp.series('css'));
    gulp.watch( watch_js, gulp.series('js'));

});
```

The package.json :

```
    {
  "name": "gulp-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Marion",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-banner": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp-combine-mq": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
    "gulp-jshint": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-purifycss": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^5.0.1",
    "jshint": "^2.10.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0"
  }
}
```

The error when running gulp :

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\Projets\gulp-test  (gulp-test@1.0.0)  
λ gulp watch  
[15:33:47] Using gulpfile C:\xampp\htdocs\Projets\gulp-test\gulpfile.js  
[15:33:47] Starting 'watch'...  
[15:33:58] Starting 'css'...  
undefined:19:9: missing '}'  
undefined:19:9: missing '}'
```

Thank you for your help I really appreciate it !

Comment: Hi, you should try to identify better where the error came from. Try to check if the error is from css or js. If you detect where is the error, we may can help you better.

Comment: Probably an error in one or more of your (s)css files, since that's the last thing it's printing. You might get more information about it if you dump the entire error object in your `display_error` function.

Comment: So I tried to identify where the error comes from and I didn't find anything relevant. I checked my sccs files and there's no syntax error, and every link seems correct to me. I'm rather bad at js, could you tell me exactly how to do the error dump ? Thank you !